# Access computer on internal network from Internet

Tags: networking, server, 13.10, ufw

My setup: Ubuntu 13.10 server with ufw, facing outside world on eth0, IP forwarding and masquerading working OK. Internal network 192.168.0/24 on eht1, no problem accessing the internet. I need to access ports 81, 8000 and 554 on 192.168.0.101 coming to/from the internet (it's a DVR for a CCTV system, which I need to monitor remotely). How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you're having problems, you may need a static IP.

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve:

- the ports under 1024 (like 554) are reserved to the Administrator (root), so any software which uses them must be executed as `root` (or safer with the `sudo` software). It's a safety measure.
- the ports you want to use should be opened, execute those commands:

  ```
  sudo ufw default deny
  sudo ufw enable
  ```

  ...to enable the ufw iptables wrapper. Then execute:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow <port number>
  ```

  ...for any port number you want to open (81,8000 and 554) to **any** type of connection from **any** host (the sintax may vary from version to version, always read `man ufw`).
  The sintax to control the ufw interface is reported [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW.), I suggest to read it.

After that you need to open the ports on your default gateway (a router or a switch) if it features an hardware firewall (like the Netgear and Belkin routers).
Now you have the **desired remote access**. :-)

Let us know by commenting down here if it's all ok & have a nice experience.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

This is how solved it:

1) Insert rules for three ports:

```
ufw allow 81
ufw allow 8000
ufw allow 554
```

2) in */etc/ufw/before.rules* I added the following lines in the NAT section (just **before** POSTROUTING):

```
:PREROUTING - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:81
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:8000
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 554 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:554
```

3) Reload the firewall:

```
ufw reload
```

In Firefox I type http//myserver.com:81 (http://myserver.com is our regular webpage) and I'm redirected to the DVR on the internal network which runs the CCTV programs I need to access from the internet (ports 8000 and 554 are used to access the system using a smartphone)

Again, thanks for the help.